# Can MSMQ automatically process queue?

Tags: c#, msmq

I have a web application that is processing some documents and emailing users and this could take some time, so I thought I'd use MSMQ to accomplish this.  I've never used MSMQ and I have a few questions about how the queuing system would process the messages I send.

1. If I send a message can I setup the program to start processing the message right away?
2. If there are 10 message in the queue can the program start automatically and process each message --one at a time--?
3. How does the program know to start processing the queue?
4. If you know the answers to my questions can you also give an example?

Thanks!

Comment: I think if you build a very small example with msmq...you'll also have all your answers (yes for all of them and even much more). Stack overflow can't (so far) replace msdn

Comment: You might also want to look into a "message bus" e.g. NServiceBus. NSB is built on top of MSMQ but provides additional capability such as publish/subscribe (multiple receivers for a single message in/on the queue/bus).